# How to read from a file which starts with particular string using unix

Tags: unix

I have a file which has one particular string which never repeats and all my data starts from this string. My requirement is to read all data beneath this string(say [string-start]) and redirect the data read into another file.

Comment: can you show an example of how the file looks?

Comment: You need to give an example of what you want to look for and what you've tried so far (in the body of your question) if you want help here.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to achieve it with `sed` in one line.

```
sed -ne 'H;1h;${g;s/.*string-start//;p}' input.txt > output.txt
```

Here's the decomposition.

- `-ne` run the following script with quiet mode.
- `h/H` - copy/append pattern space to hold space, and H will append \n to hold space first.
- `H;1h` - just used for copy all text to hold space, 1 match the first line.
- `s/.../.../` - used to replace text before `string-start` as empty, which means delete it.
- `p` - print the current pattern space.
- `${...}` - match the last line.

For example, the `input.txt` is as follows.

```
abc
def
ghistring-startjkl
mno
pqr
```

The `output.txt` will be as follows.

```
jkl
mno
pqr
```

Answer (score 0):

@Krishna Kanth: This command may be helpful . Try it :

```
sed -e 's/^.*\(search-string\)/\1/' input-file > output-file
```

Answer (score 0):

@Landys:

I tried using below command but found parsing error for the same.

$ sed -ne 'H;1h;${g;s/.*\START-OF-DATA//g;p}' < file.txt > file.out

sed: 0602-404 Function H;1h;${g;s/.*\START-OF-DATA//g;p} cannot be parsed.

Please suggest!!!

Comment: Just find it. Seems `@Landys` in your own answer will not notify me. Please try `sed -ne 'H;1h;${g;s/.*START-OF-DATA//g;p}' file.txt > file.out`. Please note that there's no "\" before `START-OF-DATA`. It's used to escape `[` in my example, and I'll make it simpler.